# IOS7: Incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: ios, malloc, checksum

I get an error

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x146f9404: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was     probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

in the following method :

```
+ (void)drawXIB_StatsDetaillees:(Statistiques*)statistiques ... {

NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Match_Statistiques_Detaillees" owner:self options:nil];
```

The error comes with the NSArray.

Here is the call of this method :

```
+ (NSString*)drawPDF:(Match*)currentMatch {

[self drawXIB_StatsDetaillees:[currentMatch statistiquesMatch] andMatch:currentMatch andTitre1:titre1 andTitre2:titre2];
```

It's a static class called through a new thread (GCD), and i think that my NSArray is released  between 2 calls of this class.

Do you agree with that ?

In this case, should i create a property with strong attribute for my array instead of create a new instance at each call ?

Thanks for your help and excuse me if my english is bad.

Stephane

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error in that method but the problem is elsewhere.

To find the source of the problem, in XCode go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and under Diagnostics tab enable all the Malloc settings and Guard Malloc.

With that, run your application again, and XCode will stop at the line causing the problem.

[image: Scheme definition]

Comment: I had this error, enabled Guard Malloc and it fixed my app. I then disabled the guard and the app carried on working fine?! Odd!